# Ola Hallengren Index Maintenance with compressed indexes

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, index-maintenance

If the Ola Hallengren index maintenance solution is installed onto a server which already has compression applied to several of the indexes, will the script respect the current compression level when rebuilding the corresponding index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - I don't see how Ola's script could possibly alter the existing compression level of an index.

If you look at the source for Ola's Index Maintenance, you will **not** see the word `COMPRESSION` anywhere.  In order to alter the compression level, his script would actually have to have the word `COMPRESSION` in it.

Comment: But on alter with rebuild (which happens past a certain fragmentation threshold), unless you specify that you want to rebuild indexes with data compression, wouldn't that mean that the rebuild will create new uncompressed indexes?

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole - no, unless you _specify_ a compression level, the existing compression level remains - you can easily verify this by running a test.